# Unable to login in open shift from eclipse

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools, openshift-cartridge, openshift-enterprise

I'm trying to login to open shift server from eclipse but getting this error "The server type, credentials, or auth scheme might be incorrect." But I'm able to login to my account from web with the same credentials.

[image: Screen shot of error]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenShift Online is not running OpenShift 3, so you need to make sure to select the correct Server Type in the drop down.

Comment: Sir I'm not getting any other server type in the options. Should i try it by installing openshift2 tools?

Comment: Is there another/older version of the tools that you can install?

Comment: sir i have installed openshift2 and it works for me... thank you soooo much !!!!!